# Any way to get -webkit-transform: rotateY to work on the Android browser?

Tags: android, css, webkit, css-transforms

While 2d rotations seem to work on my Froyo browser (Nexus One), all attempts to rotate around the Y axis just seem to rotate around the Z-axis instead. I also tried -webkit-transform: matrix3d instead of the roateY, but it also didn't work.

Is there a workaround, or are there successful reports of this being used successfully on Android?

Comment: rotate around the y-axis? Are you talking about 3D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS 3D Transformations are supported starting Android 3.0 ( http://caniuse.com/#transforms3d ).